# How to check if link redirects to another URI when I open it from mobile phone

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to check if link redirects to another URI when I open it from mobile phone (Android). I know that site, which I tested, changes its link from "www.site.com" to "www.m.site.com", when I open it from mobile phone.

I tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
httpGet.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SAMSUNG SM-G930F Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/6.2 Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Mobile Safari/537.36");

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
httpClient.execute(httpGet, context);
List<URI> redirectURIs = context.getRedirectLocations();
if (redirectURIs != null && !redirectURIs.isEmpty()) {
    for (URI redirectURI : redirectURIs) {
        System.out.println("Redirect URI: " + redirectURI);
    }
    URI mobileURI = redirectURIs.get(redirectURIs.size() - 1);
    return mobileURI.toString();
}
```

I always receive null in mobileURI. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I tried your code with apache-httpclient-4.5 and it worked...

Comment: I'm using
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.3</version>
</dependency> and try to test www.fishki.net. Which web site you tried?

Comment: Same. I tried `http://lenta.ru` redirects to `https://m.lenta.ru`.

Comment: For lenta.ru it's working but for fishki.net it's not. Do you know how this can be?

Comment: It seems that this site uses some client side script to redirect so User-Agent header doesn't matter much...

Comment: How can i detect this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test if the page will redirect after it is loaded you need to emulate target (in your case mobile) browser. You can do this with [SeleniumHQ](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) (org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:3.4.0) and [Chrome Driver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver). For example:

```
@Test
public void testSeleniumChromeDriver() throws IOException {
    // Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedriver");
    Map<String, Object> deviceMetrics = new HashMap<>();
    deviceMetrics.put("width", 360);
    deviceMetrics.put("height", 640);
    deviceMetrics.put("pixelRatio", 3.0);

    Map<String, Object> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>();
    mobileEmulation.put("deviceMetrics", deviceMetrics);
    mobileEmulation.put("userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19");

    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

    // GET the page
    driver.get("http://www.fishki.net");

    try {
        assertThat(driver.getCurrentUrl(), is("http://m.fishki.net/"));
    } finally {
        //Close the browser
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```